# GmailApp.createDraft() function daily quota?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, gmail-api

I need to know if the GmailApp.createDraft() function within Apps Script will come with the daily quota for API usage, which would limit the number to 100/day?  The documentation suggests that this function is not an API function, so would another hopefully higher quota apply?  The email is not sent, and so I assume that creating a draft does not affect my daily send quota either. Is this correct?

My account is stuck within the 60 day waiting period before my quotas are raised to those of full Business Starter subscription, but I see no reason to believe that this would affect my creating email drafts.

I do not see any quota listed here or elsewhere on the support pages. Does anyone know where I can find an answer to this?  Thanks.

Comment: You can find it here [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=en). Where Email read/write (excluding send) limit is 20,000/day for Consumer and G Suite free edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[createDraft(recipient, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createdraftrecipient,-subject,-body)

> Creates a draft email message. The size of the email (including headers) is [quota limited.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

I would guess it falls under `Email read/write (excluding send)`

[image]

but thats just a guess i dont feel like inserting 20k drafts to test it.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo.  Likewise, I'm not going to test it. You're right.